# Fading background images from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, fade

```
$('.pictures a').click(function () {
    var path = "place/of/images";
    var pics = ['pic1.JPG',
                'pic2.JPG',
                'pic3.JPG',
                'pic4.JPG'];
    var i = 0;
    var numberOfPics = pics.length - 1;
    var vaheta = setInterval(function () {
        $('body').css({ backgroundImage: 'url(' + path + pics[i] + ')' });
        if (i == numberOfPics) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 3000);
    return false;
});
```

This is the code that is currently just changing background images for me. Now I found a topic here where it says you have to load the pictures as  etc and there was this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/RnqQL/1/, this one, that is exactly what I want to do, but I don't quite know how to combine these two (my code and the fiddle).

The images will actually later be loaded with JSON from the server depending on the id of the link the person clicked to get this slideshow, this is too overwhelming for me...

Answer (score 0):

I created fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/xMrp3/1/

You can modify and use. I try to explain  what i did with comments.

```
$('.pictures a').click(function () {
    var path = "http://elegantthemes.com/preview/InStyle/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/";

    $("#wrap").empty(); // clear wrap div content
    $.getJSON('/echo/json/', function (pics) { // get json data
        var pics = ['s-1.jpg', 's-5.jpg', 's-3.jpg']; // i override json response for demo

        $.each(pics, function(i, pic) { // loop through pics array
            $('<img/>').attr('src', path + pic).appendTo($("#wrap")); // append all images to #wrap div
        });

        if (animTimeout == null) // if we didnt started anim yet
            anim(); // start animation
    });
    return false;
});

var animTimeout = null;
function anim() {
    $("#wrap img").first().appendTo('#wrap').fadeOut(500);
    $("#wrap img").first().fadeIn(500);    
    animTimeout = setTimeout(anim, 700);
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't get it to work exactly how I wanted, but I now I understand what I have to do, that is good enough and maybe even better!

Comment: Although, how could I make an event that will navigate the pictures? As in move forward and maybe backwards as well?